# How to set WebView inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to set webview inside a linearlayout. I have just created an xml Linear layout file, progress bar and a webview inside the linear layout..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progWeb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:max="100"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and java file it shows progress bar only. Webview is not shown by this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView web;
    private ProgressBar progBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        progBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progWeb);

        progBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
        String url = "http://www.google.com.pk/";

        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                System.out.println(progress);
                progBar.setProgress(progress);

                if (progress == 100) {
                    progBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                    progBar.setProgress(0);
                } else {
                    progBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        web.loadUrl(url);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the internet permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to set the orientation of `LinearLayout` to `vertical`, the default is `horizontal`

Answer (score 2):

Change your layout to

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"//==============> Here
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progWeb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:max="100"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

By default LinearLayout will set to orientation to `Horizontal`. specify the type of orientation will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

your Activity

```
public class YourActivityName extends Activity{

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);

        String url = "http://www.google.com.pk/";
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(
            Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON); 
        webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewLoad); 
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);         
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                Log.e("I am  loading Here ","Start");
                progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.e("I am  loading Here ","Override");
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;    
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work if i put the webview on top. what would you do in that situation?

Answer (score 1):

Change LinearLayout Orientation  `android:orientation="vertical"` and change the width of Progress Bar `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Also change Progressbar Gravity . `android:layout_gravity="center"`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You better use Webview inside the RelativeLayout than Linear, it should solve the problem.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progWeb"
    style="@style/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:max="100"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/progWeb"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />
```